# camel exception redelivery with hystrix

Tags: apache-camel, hystrix

I'm trying to configure a camel route so that it will retry when an endpoint within hystrix fails, in this case "direct:second".  I've created a very simple camel route (see below).  If I comment out hystrix in the route then everything works as expected in that it will retry on a failure.  Any idea how I can get retry to work with hystrix?

```
from(URI)
    .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(format("log:%s?level=ERROR", MyClass.class.getName())))
    .onException(Throwable.class)
        .maximumRedeliveries(5).redeliveryDelay("1000")
        .to("log:error?showCaughtException=true")
    .end()
    .to("direct:first")
    .hystrix()
        .hystrixConfiguration()
        .end()
        .to("direct:second")
    .endHystrix()
    .to("direct:third")
    .to("log:success?level=INFO");

// ENDPOINTS
@Consume(uri="direct:first")
public String first(String payload) {
    return payload + " first";
}

@Consume(uri="direct:second")
public String second(String payload) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    if ((rand.nextInt() % 3) == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("msg");
    }
    return payload + " second";
}

@Consume(uri="direct:third")
public String third(String payload) {
    return payload + " third";
}
```

Comment: 1. Explain the problem you want to solve instead of explaining your code.
2. What do you meant by "when hystrix fails" ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad way of putting it.  I mean when an endpoint called through hystrix fails.  It is not invoking the onException handler.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Even i tried . Raise a bug here https://github.com/apache/camel

Comment: thanks, i filed the bug here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12195